# Facebook: How to discover events in an arbitrary date range?

Tags: facebook

I'm using Facebook through a Desktop Browser.

On https://www.facebook.com/events, it is possible to discover events using a narrow set of filters including "Top", "Local" and "This Week". This is how it looks like:

[image: Event Discovery on facebook.com/events]

And then there is https://www.facebook.com/events/discovery . It allows more precise filtering with location and date:

[image: Event Discovery through facebook.com/events/search]

Unfortunately, the date filtering is partially broken. "Today", "Tomorrow", "This Week" and "Next Week" work fine. When I select "In the next month" or "Choose Date" however, no date filtering is done and events from any time are shown.

Is there a working way to discover events by arbitrary date range on Facebook?